# WPF: How to implement a generic property available at all GUI controls?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, c#-4.0, properties

is it possible to implement a property which could be specified at every GUI control (i.e. FrameworkElement)?
What I imagine is a property like Tag, however, I would prefere not to use Tag, but my own property.

EDIT:
Due to the replys of Felice and CodeNaked I gave my first experiments with Attached Dependency Properties a second try.
Although double-checking everything, the setter of my attached property (`SetAdsName()`) never will be called, although the registering of the Attached Property succeeds with no errors.
There are no error messaged -- as always with WPF.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ads="clr-namespace:WAL.UI.Lib.Ads.Binding;assembly=WAL.UI.Lib"
        Title="Demo Page" Height="350" Width="525"
>
    <Grid>
        <Label ads:AdsNameRegistry.AdsName="SpecialLabelName" Content="Some Button Caption" />
    </Grid>
</Window>


public class AdsNameRegistry : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AdsNameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( "AdsName", typeof(String), typeof(AdsNameRegistry), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( "", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender ) );

    public static void SetAdsName( UIElement element, String value )
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show( "SetAdsName(value=" + value + ")" );
            element.SetValue( AdsNameProperty, value );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Assert( false, "Exception in SetAdsName(): " + ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex );
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static String GetAdsName( UIElement element )
    {
        try
        {
            return (String) element.GetValue( AdsNameProperty );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Assert( false, "Exception in GetAdsName(): " + ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex );
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

}

My fist guess was, that SetAdsName() will never be called because there is no element  as a parent within the XAML coding.
But this seems to be a false conclusion.

Regards,
Seven

Comment: Thanks to all responders. You made my day :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, yes, you want an attached property. But you're not implementing the pattern correctly.

Never put any logic in your GetXxxx() or SetXxxx() methods. GetXxxx and SetXxxx should contain *only* calls to GetValue and SetValue, respectively:

```
public static String GetAdsName(UIElement element)
{
    return (string) element.GetValue(AdsNameProperty);
}
public static void SetAdsName(UIElement element, String value)
{
    element.SetValue(AdsNameProperty, value);
}
```

Why shouldn't they contain any other logic? Because when the XAML is loaded, your SetXxxx method won't be called. The WPF team had a choice: they could make the XAML loader use Reflection to find your SetXxxx method, and invoke it dynamically at runtime, so that your method could call SetValue; or they could remove the middleman and just call SetValue directly. They opted for the latter, because it's much simpler and much more efficient.

If you want to have side effects when your property is set, you need to specify a `propertyChangedCallback` when you construct your PropertyMetadata. In your case:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AdsNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AdsName",
        typeof(String), typeof(AdsNameRegistry),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("",
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnAdsNameChanged));

private static void OnAdsNameChanged(DependencyObject sender,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something with the new value
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I also found some seconds ago. This was the missing piece. However, I find it quite strange to implement methods that will never be called, but would lead to compiler errors when missing...

Comment: They're useful when you want to set the property programmatically. Also, they tell the compiler what types of `DependencyObject`s the property is meant to apply to. If your `SetXxxx` takes a `ListBox` as its first parameter, and your XAML tries to set it on a `Grid`, Visual Studio will give you an error. So the method signature actually is used, at least for validation.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using an [Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903943%28VS.95%29.aspx).
You can be notified when the property is attached by registering as in the following example:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty XYZProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "XYZ",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(TargetClass),
                new PropertyMetadata(OnXYZChanged)
                );
```

and implementing OnXYZChanged:

```
private static void OnXYZChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ...     
}
```

`d` will be the object you are attaching to and in `e.NewValue` you will find the new value of the property.

Comment: Hi Felice, that's what I also tried. However it seems, that there must be a parent element present in the same XAML file which provides this attachted property, right? E.g. there must be a surrounding grid in order to say <Label Grid.Row="..."/>

Comment: no, it is not necessary, an attached property is self contained, look at the link and search for some samples.You just need to write YourExtClass.Yourproperty=""

Comment: @Seven for the example you said, for have thing working you need what you said, but you can actually specify Grid.Row everiwhere not obtaining anything interesting. The effect of the property are driven by the function you define when you define the property.

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing something as method SetAdsName() will never be called. Although I do not have compiler errors or failures during runtime.

Comment: @Seven No problem, youi have to provide a notification function in your property metadata. I'll look for an example and post it on the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) to add any custom property you want. Examples include the Canvas.Left property.

Comment: OK, thank you. If you both are sure about that, I'll give that a second try and will report if I succeed. Thanks to you both for the swift reply.